# Variations on Gauss lemma

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, arithmetic

I have some issues understanding the statement and precise application domain of Gauss lemma. Here is my problem, which I believe I can solve by appealing to it: let $f, g, h$ be monic polynomials of $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ such that $fgh = X^n - 1$. I would like to concluce, since they are monic, that they are all in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$.

However, Gauss lemma states that since $X^n-1$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, it is also reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$. But can I obviously deduce that the $f, g, h$ of the hypothesis are over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I am also always disturbed by all the different forms ans subtleties of Gauss lemma, it is like it can take a specific shape for all the problem, and I might have not understood the crux of it yet...

Comment: What do you mean by $w\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @EstebanCrespi This is a type, I just edited the post: it is a $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. If $fgh = X^n-1$ with $f,g,h$ monic in $\mathbb Q[X]$ then $f,g,h \in \mathbb Z[X]$. The way to see it is using the usual statement of Gauss Lemma: *The product of primitive polynomials is primitive.* A primitive polynomial is one such that the gcd of it's coefficients is 1.

Now to see how this implies the assertion find $a,b,c$ minimum positive integers such that $af$, $bg$ and $ch$ have integer coefficients, then they are all primitive primitive so by Gauss Lemma their product 
  $$(af)(bg)(ch) = (abc)(X^n-1) $$
is also primitive, which is obviously false if $abc>1$.